# Как присвоить ключу значения списка, полученных из цикла python

Tags: python, словари, append

Пишу программу, в которой из текстового файла слова из текста - это ключи, а номера строк в которых они находятся - это значения ключей.
dic = {}

```
with open('text.txt', 'w') as kennedy:
kennedy.write('we observe \n today we \n are victory \n are part')

with open('text.txt', 'r') as kenn:
count = 0

    for line in kenn:
        count += 1
        clean_line = line.replace('\n', ' ')
        split_line = clean_line.split()

        for word in split_line:
            if word not in dic:
                lis = []
                lis.append(count)
                dic[word] = lis
            else:
                dic[word].append(count)

print(dic)
```

Возникло два вопроса:

1. Долго не могла понять как добавить списку значение при следующих итерациях, а `lis.append(count)` дает не правильные цифры. Интуитивно просто написала `dic[word].append(count)`
   , но не могу понять, dic[word] это ключ словаря, почему append работает? Из - за того, что я присвоила ранее `dic[word] = lis` и ключ стал листом? Тут я запуталась
2. Как по другому можно более грамотно и красиво решить эту задачу, не используя ennumirate и подобное. Чисто как у меня, используя самые банальные инструменты, списки и словари?

Comment: dic[word] - Это не ключ. Ключ word. А тут вы по ключу получаете значение из словаря dic. А значением у вас и есть тот самый список.

Comment: Спасибо! А не подскажите почему lis.append не работает, а именно через dic[word]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего обрати внимание на встроеный модуль fileinput, что касается кода

```
    for line in kenn:
        count += 1
        clean_line = line.replace('\n', ' ') # нужно юзать line.strip(), так как формат окончания строк различен у винды и линукса
        split_line = clean_line.split()

with open('text.txt', 'w') as kennedy:
    kennedy.write('we observe \n today we \n are victory \n are part')
    dic={}
    count = 0
    for line in kenn:
        count += 1
        split_line=line.strip().split(' ') #strip здесь удаляет перенос строк
        for word in split_line:
            if word not in dic:
                dic[word] = count
             else:
                if isinstance(dic[word],list):
                      dic[word].append(count)
                else:
#суть условия эльсе в том, что изначально у нас в качестве значения строки, следовательно следует преобразовать строку в список с одним элементом и добавить новое значение, то есть нижеследющий код обрабатывает добавление второго элемента в список
                      dic[word]=list(dic[word])
                      dic[word].append(count)
                      #dic[word]=list(dic[word],count)

print(dic)
#{'we': 1, 'observe': 1, 'today': 2, 'are': 3, 'victory': 3, 'part': 4}
```

остальной код не понял зачем, мб не разобрался в вопросе

Comment: Спасибо! Да , моя вина объяснила не понятно совсем. Дело в том, что на выходе должен быть словарь, в котором ключи это все уникальные слова в файле, а значения - списки, в которых элементы - номера строк,  в которых встречаются эти слова. Так как 'we' допустим встречается в первой и во второй строке, была необходимость, что бы получилась такая пара 'we': [1, 2] . Собственно вот получилось то, что получилось, код работает, но вопрос как раз был почему dic[word].append(count) работает как надо, а если через список делать lis.append(count), то цифры в листе не правильные добавляются

Comment: обновил код, надеюсь всё понятно?

Comment: Да , поняла, спасибо)